# Adding a line at the end of every page in proc report

Tags: sas, proc, proc-report

I am just wondering how can I add a line at the end of every page of my report.

Thanks

Comment: If the answer works for you select the answer as selected answer.  It let's others know it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the footnote option.

```
footnote1  '';
```